# Solving Nonhomogeneous Nonlinear First Order ODE with Power on the Derivative and Factors into Two Linear ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system

I was recently playing around with a problem for fun(as one does in grad school) and came across an nonhomogeneous nonlinear ODE and I'm hoping someone can explain how to solve it:
$$
y^{2}-\left(1+f(x)\right)y\frac{dy}{dx}+f(x)\frac{dy}{dx}^{2} = \left( y-\frac{dy}{dx} \right) \left( y-f(x)\frac{dy}{dx} \right)=k
$$
I've looked through most of my books that I would think touch on it... 2 different undergrad ODE books(Zill and Haberman), 2 Dynamical Systems books (Verhulst and Sternberg), and Nonlinear ODEs by Jordan and Smith... but with no luck.

I'm really at a loss on this. I just don't know how to go about solving an ODE of this form. Nor, it appears, do my textbooks.

For w/e it's worth, thus far, Dr. Google has only delivered answers for how to solve cases without a power on the derivative. Which is what the profs in my dept, whom I've asked thus far, have also scratched their heads at.

**Any help would be greatly appreciated.**

---

Anybody? Any suggestions?

I'm pretty much out of ideas other than plugging in different functions to see what happens.

Comment: So, I think I have a method for solving this now and plan on testing it later tonight. By subtracting k from both sides to set up the equation:
$$
(y^{2}-k)-\left(1+f(x)\right)y\frac{dy}{dx}+f(x)\frac{dy}{dx}^{2}=0
$$
I can set up the quadratic equation to derive two ODEs; and, the sum of their solutions should satisfy the original equation.

Comment: Yea... That really didn't help much...
$$
\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{\left( 1+f(x) \right)y \pm \sqrt{\left( 1+f(x) \right)^{2}y^{2}-4f(x)\left( y^{2}-k\right)} }{2f(x)}
$$
$$
y=\frac{\left( 1+f(x) \right)\frac{dy}{dx} \pm \sqrt{\left( 1+f(x) \right)^{2}\frac{dy}{dx}^{2}-4\left( f(x) \frac{dy}{dx}^{2}-k \right) }}{2}
$$

Comment: I mean sure, in both forms I get some reduction under the radical... But not much...

$$
\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{\left( 1+f(x) \right)y \pm \sqrt{\left( 1-f(x) \right)^{2}y^{2}+4f(x)k} }{2f(x)}
$$

$$
y=\frac{\left( 1+f(x) \right)\frac{dy}{dx} \pm \sqrt{\left( 1-f(x) \right)^{2}\frac{dy}{dx}^{2}+4k}}{2}
$$